# Using Attribute Scalar_Storage_Order in ada with gcc 6.2.1

Tags: gcc, ada, endianness, gnat

I'm currently trying to find a solution to control the storage order for elements within a record in ADA.

I'm using gcc 6.2.1 which doesnt recognize the `Scalar_Storage_Order` attribute ( even though the attribute is clearly referenced in the gcc 6.2 GNAT reference manual).

```
type Rec is record

      Data1 : T_Data;
      Data2 : T_Data;

   end record;

for Rec use
      record

         Data1      at 0 range 0 .. 15;
         Data2      at 0 range 0 .. 15;

      end record;

for Rec'Bit_Order use System.High_Order_First;
for Rec'Scalar_Storage_Order use System.High_Order_First;

error: unrecognized attribute "Scalar_Storage_Order"
```

Is there an alternative that I can use to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you give tools versions and the command used to compile code ? it may help others. I have personnaly used this pragma in Ada 2012 using Gnat Community as well as PRO version without any issue whatsoever. However I was almost exclusively using GPR files and GPR build (so not using gcc directly "myself").

Comment: This is indeed curious. The attribute was added to GNAT [a long time ago](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=f91510fca5547ad6e73ea9153ba1bac2fefcd915) and works on GNAT FSF 6.3.0; the version that ships with Debian 9.13 (Stretch).

Comment: @LoneWanderer I'm not actually using commands directly. I'm using GNAT Studio Community as my editor/builder and GNATPro 6.2.1 as my compiler.

Comment: What is "S"? Please show more of your code, including the record declaration and the declaration of S (if they are not the same).

Comment: Post edited for more clarificaction.

Comment: Does anything change if `Data1` and `Data2` don't overlap?